# jQuery animate DIV from center to fullwidth with same height/width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div from small size to full screen size and then hide, but the problem is, its not centered and width and height is not same, how can I handle it, can somebody please suggest?

This is what I have created so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".circle-centered" ).animate({
 width:"100%",
 height:"100%",
        marginTop: -$('.circle-centered').outerHeight()/2
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.circle-centered {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 3;
 background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-centered"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to animate the "top" property also as youo have it set to 50%

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".circle-centered" ).animate({
 width:"100%",
 height:"100%",
    top:0,
        marginTop: -$('.circle-centered').outerHeight()/2
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
.circle-centered {
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -10px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 z-index: 3;
 background: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle-centered"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do I control width and height? I also wanted to make make height and width same size

Comment: You have set them to be 100% in the call to the animate method. You could set these to be fixed width/height as currently they are relative to the parent element, so the actual dimensions will change depending on where you are displaying the circle. Or you could set the width/height property of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you set the margin-top: -10px, but with my test it's working well.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/tr9ojbxn/

I just added top to the animation.
Let me know.

Cheers